Spring Boot and JobRunr - NestedFileSystemProvider not found

Spring Boot Version - 3.3.1
Jobrunr Version - 7.2.2
DB client - Mongo
Provider - AmazonDocumentDB
Java - 21

With above confiugration whenever my application was starting i was getting this error -
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider: Provider org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider not found
But when i am using mongoDb cluseter from mongo atlas, i am not facing this issue.
Adding the spring-boot-loader dependency, resolved the issue. Can anyone explain me the reason for this?

No idea to be honest... Normally it should be added automatically by spring boot I would think.
